# separable or non separable? alternative way to solve the equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've got a problem with this diff. equation:

> $h'(2h-z)(\frac{1}{2} -z)= 2h (h-2)$

I tried hard to somehow transform the first equation in order to reach a separable equation but failed to get a solution. Is there a way to justify the author's calculations. I don't ask for a complete solution, just some help to somehow manage this problem. I really hope that someone could help me.

Comment: Sorry, disregard, it was misleaded.

Comment: The numerical tests show that $h^3 (h-2) = K (\frac{1}{2} -z)^{-4}$ is NOT solution of $h'(2h-z)(\frac{1}{2} -z)= 2h (h-2)$. Probably, there is a typo somewhere.

Comment: Since there is a typo, it's a lost of time to try to solve the EDO $h'(2h-z)(\frac{1}{2} -z)= 2h (h-2)$. Nevertheless, solving it is theoretically possible in considering the inverse function $z(h)$. The non linear equation $(2h-z)(\frac{1}{2} -z)= 2h (h-2)z'$ is a Riccati EDO which can be transformed into à linear EDO. But solving it would be too arduous.

Comment: If the typo is not in your copy, it is in the book ! See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

$$h^3 (h-2) = K (\frac{1}{2} -z)^{-4}$$
is not solution of $$h'(2h-z)(\frac{1}{2} -z)= 2h (h-2)$$
it is solution of :
$$h'(2h-3)(\frac{1}{2} -z)= 2h (h-2)$$
Obviously, the variables are separable and it is easy to solve it, which leads to the expected implicit equation.

Comment: thx JJacquelin I really appreciate your effort, now i see it. But how did you recognize the typo, did you use a software to conduct a numerical tests?

Comment: Nothing very clever : giving a numerical value for $h$ and for $k$, compute ne numerical value of $h'$ from the ODE. Also, differentiate the expected formula of the solution. $K$ disappears. Compute the numetical value of $\frac{dh}{dz}$. This value was not equal to the value of $h'$. So the the ODE and the expected solution where not consistent.

Comment: Moreover, starting from $h^3(h-2)=K (\frac{1}{2}-z)^{-4}$ one can search of which ODE it is solution "backward method".  This leads to $h'(2h-3) (\frac{1}{2}-z)=2h(h-2)$